# Data rendering on Django Channels from Python websocket

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel

I am trying to send data from my python websocket client to Django Channels server.

I am using the [python web socket client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/).

**my-websocket.py**

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print (message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print ("eroror:", error)

def on_close(ws):
    print ("### closed ###")
    # Attemp to reconnect with 2 seconds interval
    time.sleep(2)
    initiate()

def on_open(ws):
    print ("### Initiating new websocket connectipython my-websocket.pyon ###")
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(30000):
            # Sending message with 1 second intervall
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
            # ws.send(json.dumps("Hello %d" % i))
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print ("thread terminating...")
    _thread.start_new_thread(run, ())

def initiate():
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:8000/ws/power/room/",
        on_message = on_message,
        on_error = on_error,
        on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open

    ws.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    initiate()
```

My consumer of Django Channels is

**consumer.py**

```
class EchoConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'power_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        # Receive message from WebSocket

    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

        # Receive message from room group

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

**Error**

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/power/room/ [127.0.0.1:54591]
WebSocket CONNECT /ws/power/room/ [127.0.0.1:54591]
Exception inside application: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 179, in __call__
    return await self.inner(receive, self.send)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 41, in coroutine_call
    await inner_instance(receive, send)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 59, in __call__
    [receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 52, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 108, in __call__
    return await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 388, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\db.py", line 13, in thread_handler
    return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 123, in thread_handler
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 105, in dispatch
    handler(message)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\channels\generic\websocket.py", line 60, in websocket_receive
    self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
  File "C:\Users\Suleman\PycharmProjects\power\myChannels\consumers.py", line 41, in receive
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
  Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/power/room/ [127.0.0.1:54591]
```

As you can see the from the error that i am able to have handshake between websocket but data is not rendering on the webpage.

Comment: Is Django-Channels compatible with `websocket-client`? I use reconnecting websockets in a `.js` file that I use to communicate with Django Channels.

Comment: I don't know. I can't find this answer anywhere; thus, seeking assistance here.

Comment: Hi again. I think you should use a framework with including reconnecting websockets directly in a javascript file or in your Django template, that connects to Django channels using the websocket bridge and `routing.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `async` to your `chat_message` function [as per the documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html) and see if that helps?

```
async def chat_message(self, event):
    """
    Called when someone has messaged our chat.
    """
    ...
```

If you do not use sync with async properly then things will not get executed in a coordinated fashion. If you use async and await properly, then your webscocket should have time to establish the handshake and begin the transfer of data **before closing.**

Also, it looks like your group_send might need to change to include `await`, and I think you might be closing `async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)` too early.

```
# Send message to room group
async_to_sync(
   await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        room.group_name,
       {
            'type': 'chat_message',
            'message': message
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: No its not working, still facing the error-----
send: b'\x81\x87\xf5\x0e5\x9b\xbdkY\xf7\x9a.\x05'
send: b'\x88\x82\x19\xe4\xabB\x1a\x0c'
### closed ###
send: b'\x81\x87`EV:( :V\x0feg'
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function on_open.<locals>.run at 0x000001EED6A5EF28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-websocket.py", line 24, in run

Comment: Ok, can you update your question to reflect the new code please?

Comment: If i use the chat program of Django Channels tutorial, it operates, but i am unable to send messages from web socket client.

Comment: Again I'm not sure you should be using websocket-client. I think you should be adding Reconnecting WebSocket in a `.js` file or in your Django templates: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reconnecting-websocket. Then you need to use the "send" and "receive" functions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking carefully to the log, it seems that the websocket gets connected:

```
 WebSocket CONNECT /ws/power/room/ [127.0.0.1:54591]
```

But the consumer `receive` method raises a JSON exception, certainly because its argument `text_data` is `None`.